# Export Raster from R-INLA

Tags: r, gis, arcgis

so I am in dire need of help. I have finally managed to construct my R-INLA model and get it to graph as needed. via the code below:

First I create the stacks (note this is the very end of my INLA process, the mesh etc has already been done)

```
stk.abdu = inla.stack(data = list(y = 1, e = 0), A = list(abdu.mat, 1),tag = 'abdu', effects = list(list(i = 1:sc.mesh.5$n), data.frame(Intercept = 1,dwater=winter.abdu$dwater,elev=winter.abdu$elev,forest=winter.abdu$forest,developed=winter.abdu$developed,openwater=winter.abdu$OpenWater,barren=winter.abdu$barren,shrubland=winter.abdu$shrubland,herb=winter.abdu$herb,planted=winter.abdu$planted,wetland=winter.abdu$wetland,dist=winter.abdu$dwater)))
stk.quad = inla.stack(data = list(y = 0, e = 0.1), A = list(quad.mat, 1),tag = 'quad', effects = list(list(i = 1:sc.mesh.5$n), data.frame(Intercept = 1,dwater=dummy$dwater,elev=dummy$elev,forest=dummy$forest,developed=dummy$developed,openwater=dummy$openwater,barren=dummy$barren,shrubland=dummy$shrubland,herb=dummy$herb,planted=dummy$planted,wetland=dummy$wetland,dist=dummy$dwater)))
stk.prd<-inla.stack(data = list(y = NA), A = list(Aprd, 1),tag = 'prd', effects = list(list(i = 1:sc.mesh.5$n), data.frame(Intercept = 1,dwater=prddf2$dwater,elev=prddf2$elev,forest=prddf2$forest,developed=prddf2$developed,openwater=prddf2$openwater,barren=prddf2$barren,shrubland=prddf2$shrubland,herb=prddf2$herb,planted=prddf2$planted,wetland=prddf2$wetland,dist=prddf2$dwater)))
stk.all.prd = inla.stack(stk.abdu,stk.quad,stk.prd)
```

Next I fit my model

```
ft.inla.prd<-inla(y ~ 0 + Intercept + elev  + dwater + forest+ developed + f(inla.group(dist,n=50,method="quantile"),model="rw1",scale.model=TRUE)+f(i,model=sc.spde),family="binomial",data=inla.stack.data(stk.all.prd),control.predictor = list(A = inla.stack.A(stk.all.prd),compute=TRUE),E=inla.stack.data(stk.all.prd)$e,control.compute=list(dic = TRUE),control.fixed=list(expand.factor.strategy="INLA"))
```

Then I change the predicted values from logit to probabilities

```
ft.inla.prd$newfield <- exp(ft.inla.prd$summary.random$i$mean)/(1 + exp(ft.inla.prd$summary.random$i$mean))
```

And finally I use inla.mesh.project and levelplot to create my image

```
xmean <- inla.mesh.project(projgrid,ft.inla.prd$newfield)
levelplot(xmean, col.regions=topo.colors(99), main='Probability of Presence',xlab='', ylab='', scales=list(draw=FALSE))
```

So my problem is that I now want to export this data (what is projected as the graph) as a raster so that I can work with it in ArcGIS. However, I have not been able to find a way to do so.

Any input is greatly appreciated